# Was this twist from the last episode of V's second season foreshadowed?

Tags: v-2009

Spoilers for the last episode of season 2 of the *V* remake. My question is about one of the twists in this episode, namely

> that Erica's old partner and boss are not V agents, but rather have been spying on her all this time so they can bring her in to Project Ares.  Were there any clues that they weren't spying on her for the Vs this whole time?

I'm curious if there were hints that I missed.

Comment: I thought for a moment you were talking of a tv version of 'V for Vendetta'

Comment: Could it have been a last minute script re-write to desperately make V exciting to hopefully pull in funding for another season? It was a good attempt, killing off annoying characters, bringing some nostalgia by injecting original 80's series people into the storyline, hinting that another series would be filled with war, and the visitors would get their comeuppance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall any indication that Erica's old partner (Chris Bolling) and her boss (Paul Kendrick) were anything other than FBI agents who suspected she might be a sleeper agent for the Fifth Column.  I was even starting to suspect they might be Visitors themselves, until this last episode.

Comment: I'd assumed they were V this whole time, until the reveal.